# Unix Password Management Keyring

Tags: unix, password-management

I am looking for a password manager for a command-line Unix environment. So far all I can find are keyring applications for Windows, Linux, and Mac. But no command-line Unix interfaces.

My main goal is to be able to access a password keyring through an SSH connection to a machine that has no graphical user interface. If there are no good unix password keyrings out there, what would be a better way to store personal passwords in a central location?

Comment: You don't want to run a X server on your local system?

Comment: No, I want the ability to run Putty off my flash drive and execute a single command so I don't have to install an X server on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to just use gpg encrypted files. You can make your encrypted files available over nfs or distribute them via rsync. You could also go with a pull model and distribute it with svn or git or whatever vcs you prefer. Just make sure you have a good secure passphrase if you're distributing them at all. You may also want to look into gpg-agent.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [pwsafe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwsafe) it has problems with usability, but does the job.

There is also a [cpm](http://www.harry-b.de/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=harry:cpm), but i have not tested it. Using KeePass in console is also [possible](http://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/scr_sc_index.html).